# Code for leaving alone unknown in a equation?

Tags: c#, equation

I have an equation like this:

```
a = b(x-c)^d-e(x-f)^g
```

`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f` and `g` are known numbers that changes. `x` is unknown.

I would like to find x. How can I do this with C# code?

Comment: Solve for the equation for `x`, (x = ...) and then plug in the known values.

Comment: C# doesn't have any equation-solving capabilities.

You need to work out the maths (and be *very* aware that in C#, `^` is a bitwise XOR, *not* exponentiation) and then write normal C# code to compute `x` from the other values.

Comment: The way you write it, it looks more like `b` and `e` are _methods_ taking one argument and returning a value.

Comment: There is the brute force solution. For example, to find usable `x` values between `-10000` and `10000`, you could say `Enumerable.Range(-10000, 20001).Where(x => a == b(x-c)^d-e(x-f)^g)`. Note the difference between `=` and `==` in C#. Note that `b(x-c)` is a call or invocation of a method `b`, not multiplication. (Multiblication would be `b*(x-c)`.) And as said above, `^` is bitwise XOR, not exponentiation. Note that integer arithmetic will happily "wrap around" on overflows unless you do an effort to use `checked` context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a, b, c, d, e, f and g are known numbers that changes

So, do you *know* values and want to find values of `x` that fit the equation?  Or are you trying to come up with an equation *in terms of those variables*?  I'm pretty sure there's no closed-form equation for x based on that formula.

If you *know* the values of `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`,and `g`, then you can use a [root-finding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) to find values of x.

First reorder your equation to

```
b(x-c)^d-e(x-f)^g - a = 0
```

Then use a root-finding algorithm.

The Newton Method and Secant Method are fairly easy to codify, and you can probably find existing C# implementations online.

Comment: My English is not good. Also i am very new to coding. My problem is the first question that you have written. I can't understand second question clearly. I will research for root-finding algorithm.

Comment: This answer takes the interpretation that given numbers `a`, ..., `g` and the unknown variable `x` are real or complex numbers. The circumflex `^` is probably exponentiation, then.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen "a, b, c, d, e, f and g are known numbers"

Comment: OK, but there was not much context, and I wasn't sure if it made sense to consider this some kind of [Diophantine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) problem where all number are integers. In that case other methods could be relevant. However with only one unknown, there is not much "degrees of freedom", and for "most" choices of `a`, ..., `g` there might be no integer (or rational) solutions. In any case, a computer algebra tool would be easier to apply than to write code in C#.

Answer (score 0):

NCalc could do what you need.

The link is here: http://ncalc.codeplex.com/.

**Example functionality**

```
  Expression e = new Expression("2 + 3 * 5");
  Debug.Assert(17 == e.Evaluate());
```

Comment: Does it solve equations though?